# How do I insert new values into a mysql json array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am testing this example.

[JSON_TABLE – The Best of Both Worlds](https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/)

I understand that t1 is the table and people the array but where do I put the name of the column?

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (
        '{ "people": [
            { "name":"John Smith",  "address":"780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103"}, 
            { "name":"Sally Brown",  "address":"75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103"}, 
            { "name":"John Johnson",  "address":"1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071"}
         ] }'
    );
```

They call the column json_col but they only use it in a select query like this.

```
SELECT people.* 
FROM t1, 
     JSON_TABLE(json_col, '$.people[*]' COLUMNS (
                name VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
                address VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.address')
     ) people;
```

Comment: `json_col` is the name of the column ( `CREATE TABLE t1(json_col JSON);` ). For insertion, you can also use `INSERT INTO t1(json_col) VALUES (...)`

Comment: Thanks Pavel, that works.

Comment: I've also added this comment as answer, co it will be more visible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_col` is the name of the column ( `CREATE TABLE t1(json_col JSON);` ).

For insertion, you can also use `INSERT INTO t1(json_col) VALUES (...)`

Comment: How do I update the same array after the new value is inserted? So I can use a where clause on for example an id column.

Comment: Exactly, json_col (you can name the column as you want) is just a regular column with data type `JSON`.